# How to split strings by spaces in DM script

Tags: string, parsing, dm-script

I need to read/load a series of strings in a line in the text file by DM scripting,  there are spaces between the strings, the number of spaces is not fixed, may 8 spaces between two adjacent strings,   but 7 spaces between other two adjacent strings, I need let the DM know that when they encounter a space, it is a new string, but if it encounter spaces continually , it does not count a new string, until it encounters an non space characters.

Any suggestions I appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example script to show how to parse a space-delimited string:

```
TagGroup ParseText( string inputString ) {
    // initialize a tag list to store parsing results
    TagGroup tgWordList = NewTagList();
    //
    while( inputString.len() > 0 ) {
        number pos = inputString.find( chr(32) );
        if( pos > 0 ) {         // "space" (i.e. ASC code: 32) is found and it's not the leading character
            string str = inputString.left( pos );
            tgWordList.TagGroupInsertTagAsString( tgWordList.TagGroupCountTags(), str );
            inputString = inputString.right( inputString.len() - pos );
        }
        else if( pos == 0 ) {   // first chracter is "space"
            inputString = inputString.right( inputString.len() - 1 );
            if( inputString == chr(32) ) break;
        }
        else {                  // no "space" found in whole string
            tgWordList.TagGroupInsertTagAsString( tgWordList.TagGroupCountTags(), inputString );            
            break;
        };
    };
    return tgWordList;
};

string test = "how the DM script recognize the spaces between the strings";
TagGroup tg = test.parseText();
tg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow(0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is standard string manipulation. You need to construct your own method to parse the string using the available String commands documented in the F1 help under "Objects:String Object", I think there is even an example on parsing:

[image]

The commands you most likely need are

```
Number len( String str )
Returns the length of a String.

String left( String str, Number count )
Returns leftmost count characters of a string.

String mid( String str, Number offset, Number count )    
Returns count characters of a string starting at offset.

String right( String str, Number count )    
Returns rightmost count characters of a string.

Number find( String s1, String s2 )    
Returns the index of the first occurrence of the substring 's2' in 's1', or '-1' if there is no such occurrence.
```

You'll need a `while` loop using `find` which continues as long as a `" "` is found or to the end of the string.